# Can you change CSS for view in Controller in Rails?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a view (let's call it View #1) that allows the user to select a certain table to view using a dropdown menu on a form. That parameter is then passed to my controller. What I want to do is get my controller to take that parameter and use it to change the visibility of elements on the view it directs to (View #2).

View #2 has 3 tables. Only one table should be visible at any given time once my method in my Controller runs. Currently, all 3 tables have unique IDs and they have a display:none attribute in the CSS file. So, if the user selects "1" from View #1, I want View #2 to set table 1's display to block and table 2 and 3 to display:none. Can I do this in the Controller or am I required to do this in JavaScript? If I have to do this in JavaScript, how do I pass the parameter value from the controller to the JS function call?

Comment: Usually you modify the emitted HTML to use different styles rather than changing the CSS. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Even if you do the actual logic on the controller, you'll need to either wire up a submit when the user makes a selection or you'll need to use javascript to send the selection across the wire.  Basically, if there's a way to do this, it's well beyond me.

Comment: No, tadman, just straight Ruby, HTML, and CSS. All I want to do is change the properties of the tables as needed (visible or hidden) using whatever selection they chose when they submitted the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably break out each table into its own partial and only render the one you want to display:

```
def some_action
  @table_to_show = "table_1"
  # table_1 should be determined by the user's selection from View #1
  # probably something like: @table_to_show = params[:user_selection]
end
```

and in your view #2:

```
<%= render @table_to_show %>
```

which will in turn render the template: _table_1.html.erb

You can use CSS/js, but probably shouldn't for something that is handled at the controller level.

Comment: This worked perfectly, @johndavid400, and it was so simple for me to implement. I know SO doesn't like comments used to say thanks, but in this case, a thanks is in order!